# What is the best Linq Query for this?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with this column:

```
Code        //int
Type        //int
Point       //int
```

I want to have query that do this work:

Based on `Code` and `Type` do a select and add sum of point to `Point`. I think I can't explain what I want correctly and for this reason I show you the result what I want in below.

**My table:**

```
Code           Type            Point        Date
1              1               10           someDate
1              1               20           someDate
1              2               10           someDate
1              1               30           someDate
1              2               10           someDate
2              1               30           someDate
2              2               20           someDate
2              1               10           someDate
1              2               10           someDate
1              1               10           someDate
3              2               20           someDate
```

**The result I want :**

```
row[0] : Code:1, Type:1, Point:70,
row[1] : Code:1, Type:2, Point:30,
row[2] : Code:2, Type:1, Point:40,
row[3] : Code:2, Type:2, Point:20,
row[4] : Code:3, Type:2, Point:20,
```

**UPDATE:**
If I want a result like this what is the best query?

```
row[0] : Code:1, pointType1:70, pointType2:30,
row[0] : Code:2, pointType1:40, pointType2:20,
row[0] : Code:3, pointType1:0, pointType2:20,
```

Comment: In your example row[0] and row[2] have the same key.

Comment: I have update my question. please see it again.

Answer (score 3):

You can group on `Code` and `Type` property your list and then Project the both keys with aggregate sum of the `Point` property from the grouping result like:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=> new { x.Code, x.Type})
                 .Select(g=> 
                             new { 
                                   Code = g.Key.Code, 
                                   Type= g.Key.Type, 
                                   Point = g.Sum(x=>x.Point)
                             })
                 .ToList();
```

### UPDATE:

after question example output updated, the following would give you expected result:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=> x.Code)
                     .Select(g=> 
                                 new { 
                                       Code = g.Key.Code, 
                                       PointType1= g.Where(x=>x.Type==1)
                                                    .Sum(x=>x.Point)
                                                   Key.Type, 
                                       PointType2 = g.Where(x=>x.Type==2)
                                                     .Sum(x=>x.Point)
                                 })
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I get this error : `invalid anonymous type member declarator anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simle name or member access` In `g.Sum(x=>x.Point)`

Comment: Why everyone give me negative point?

Comment: Because you made a mistake in how you want your result to be.

Comment: They give me negative point because it's easier that to edit question. :(

Comment: @mohammad Edit yourself, you know the mistake.

Comment: @mohammad You receive negative votes because you ask a pretty basic question which you should be able to easily solve yourself with a little thinking and looking at the documentation.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad please see my update.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I get this Error : `string does not contain a definition for and no exception method accepting a first argument of type string` in the `Code = g.Key.PamCode,`

Comment: that is not related to this question,  i would suggest  to ask a new question for that